# Stop bewilder when go up

Tags: blood

How to stop bewilder ? When I siting and I go to get up then I bewilder.What is caused this and how can I treat this?

Comment: do you mean feeling dizzy? Light headed?

Comment: Yes but not always I feel to "faint"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like [orthostatic hypotension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthostatic_hypotension). There may be underlying causes, so you should ask a doctor about it, but you can help alleviate symptoms immediately by increasingly salt and water intake or wearing compression stockings.